# Brezis' Exercise 4.7

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $1 \le q < p \le \infty$. Let $a:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ be measurable such that $au \in L^q (\Omega)$ for all $u \in L^p (\Omega)$. Then $a \in L^r (\Omega)$ with
> $$
> r = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{pq}{p-q} &\text{if } p < \infty,\\
> q &\text{if } p=\infty.
> \end{cases}
> $$

Could you confirm if my below attempt is correct?

---

**Proof** The case $p = \infty$ follows by picking $u =1$. Let's assume $p < \infty$. We define a linear operator
$$
T : L^p (\Omega) \to L^q (\Omega), u \mapsto au.
$$

Let's prove that the graph of $T$ is closed. Let $u,u_n \in L^p (\Omega)$ and $f \in L^q (\Omega)$ such that $(u_n, Tu_n) \to (u, f)$ in $L^p \times L^q$.  [There is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4301365/convergence-in-mathcal-l-1-implies-mu-a-e-convergence-for-a-subsequence) a sub-sequence $\varphi$ of $\mathbb N$ such that $u_{\varphi (n)} \to u$ $\mu$-a.e. Hence  $Tu_{\varphi (n)} \to Tu$ $\mu$-a.e. Clearly, $(Tu_{\varphi(n)})$ is a Cauchy sequence. So $Tu_{\varphi (n)} \to Tu$ in $L^q$. Hence $Tu=f$ $\mu$-a.e. By closed graph theorem, $T$ is continuous. Then there is $C \in [0, \infty)$ such that $\|T u\|_q \le C \|u\|_p$ for all $u \in L^p$, or equivalently
$$
\int |au|^q \le C^q \bigg ( \int |u|^p \bigg )^{q/p}
\quad \forall  u \in L^p (\Omega).
$$

Notice that $|u| \in L^p (\Omega) \iff |u|^q \in L^{p/q} (\Omega)$. So
$$
\int |a|^q |v|\le C^q \|v\|_{p/q}
\quad \forall  v \in L^{p/q} (\Omega).
$$

We consider a linear map
$$
F:L^{p/q} (\Omega) \to \mathbb R, v \mapsto \int |a|^q v.
$$

Then $|Fv| \le C^q \|v\|_{p/q}$ for all $v \in L^{p/q} (\Omega)$. Hence $F$ is continuous. Let $k$ be the exponent conjugate of $p/q$, i.e., $\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{p/q}=1$. This implies $k=p/(p-q)$. We have the isometric isomorphism [$L^{p/q} (\Omega)^* = L^k (\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4506440/let-e-be-a-hilbert-space-and-p-in-1-infty-then-l-p-l-p-wi). So there is a unique $b \in L^k (\Omega)$ such that
$$
F v= \int bv
\quad \forall  v \in L^{p/q} (\Omega).
$$

[It follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4546113/bochner-integral-is-f-g-mu-a-e-if-their-integrals-are-equal-on-every-meas) that $|a|^q=b$ $\mu$-a.e. and thus $|a| \in L^{qk} (\Omega)$. Finally, $qk = pq(p-q)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: It seems that under the assumptions of your posting,$\sigma$-finiteness is not needed. All you are using is the fact that a sequence $f_n$ that converges to $f$ in $L_p$ $(1\leq p<\infty$) converges point wise almost surely along a subsequence, which does not require $\sigma$-finiteness. The [case](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4212203/121671) $p=q$ in which $r=\infty$ -not considered in your problem- does require some sort of semi-finiteness ($\sigma$-finiteness will do of course).

Comment: Your solution, after continuity of the operator $f\mapsto a f$ is done is very similar to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2675536/121671).